# AngularJS Changes to URL Routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

We have a website which currently has routing set up to be `site.com/products/:id`, so a sample URL may be `site.com/products/104`.
We no longer want the `ID` in the URL, and would like the actual product name instead. So we would want it as `site.com/products/produc-name`

How would we go about making this change? We are using *ui-router*. I'm not sure what other information is needed, so please ask away. Seeking any guidance you can give. Thank you.

The router is:

```js
.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch'])
            .config(config)
            .run(run);
    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$authProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    controller: 'HomeController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
                    resolve: {
                        alreadyLoggedIn: alreadyLoggedIn
                    }
                })
                .state('product', {
                    url: '/product/:id',
                    controller: 'ProductController',
                    title: "Product",
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
```

And then to call the product, we use

```html
<a ng-href="/#/product/{{::value.id}}">
```

Comment: It should be an easy change, provided your product names are all unique. Without the code that sets up your routes and the code that creates the links to them, no one is going to be able to help you much.

Comment: Thanks, edited the original question to include code samples, hope that's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you need to do 3 things.

1) Change your product state to something like

```
.state('product', {
     url: '/product/:productName',
     controller: 'ProductController',
     title: "Product",
     templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html',
     controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
```

2) change your hrefs to something like

```
<a ng-href="/#/product/{{::value.productName}}">
```

3) Change ProductController to find your products by name rather than the id.

Obviously if the productName field isn't actually productName, you'll have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't know why I was looking for something more complicated - this solved my problem just fine!